# Mongod service running but not connecting in browser

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, localhost

**Background:**

- Using vagrant virtual box running Ubuntu on a macbook
- Having installed the mongoid gem in a new rails application
- I am given `localhost:27017` as the port that the mongodb server is running on.

From the command line, I am able to start/stop the mongodb server and interact with the default database through the mongo console.

**Problem:** I am not able to connect to `localhost:27017` from the browser as suggested by various tutorials to confirm that mongodb is running correctly.

**Question:** What are some commands, debugging protocols, or log files that I can use to locate the cause of my problem? (i.e. why I can use the mongodb service via command line but can not connect in browser).

**And:** Based on the background information, if there is a common installation and set-up step that I might have missed, what could that be?

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** possible to connect to the main mongodb port using a browser; your tutorials may be wrong.

The mongodb service does not use http, or any of the other protocols which your browser is familiar with; instead it uses a [specific MongoDB protocol](https://superuser.com/a/1123685/217986), and your browser will not be able to communicate over it.

There is a feature of MongoDB which can expose a [REST API over http](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-status-interface); perhaps this is what your tutorials are asking you to use, *but*:

1. This interface is deprecated, and disabled by default. The advice has for a long time been to make sure this is disabled for security reasons.
2. If enabled, it listens on a different port e.g. 28017